# Rewriting Objects to another NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to rewrite one element from `self.tableData` to another.

my `NSMutableArray`:

```
self.tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                          [[Cell alloc] initWithName:@"dawdw" andImage:@"dwddw" andDescription:@"dawdw" andTypes:@"dawwd dawwd" andforWho:@"dwaadw"],
                          [[Cell alloc] initWithName:@"Kabanos" andImage:@"spodwwdwdrt.jpg" andDescription:@"dwdw" andTypes:@"dwdw dww" andforWho:@"dawwd"],
                          [[Cell alloc] initWithName:@"dwwd" andImage:@"dwwd" andDescription:@"dwwd" andTypes:@"wdwd daww" andforWho:@"dadawwa"],nil];

NSMutableArray *newarray;
[newarray addObject:self.tableData[0]];
```

But it's not working, maybe it's a newbie question but i have never before worked with arrays with many objects inside.

With self.tableData[0] i men rewrite object

```
[[Cell alloc] initWithName:@"dawdw" andImage:@"dwddw" andDescription:@"dawdw" andTypes:@"dawwd dawwd" andforWho:@"dwaadw"],
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not an adequate problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *newarray;
[newarray addObject:self.tableData[0]];
```

The problem with the code above is that you haven't created an array for `newArray` to point to, so the value of `newArray` is `nil`. Do this instead:

```
NSMutableArray *newarray = [NSMutableArray array];
[newarray addObject:self.tableData[0]];
```

Now `newArray` will point to a valid mutable array to which you can add objects.

Also, realize that even with the fixed code, `newArray[0]` will point to the very same object that you've stored in `self.tableData[0]`, not a copy. If you want it to point to a different object that contains similar data, you should either make a copy of the object or instantiate a new one, e.g.:

```
[newarray addObject:[self.tableData[0] copy]];
```

or:

```
[newarray addObject:[[Cell alloc] initWithName:@"dawdw" andImage:@"dwddw" andDescription:@"dawdw" andTypes:@"dawwd dawwd" andforWho:@"dwaadw"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to init new array. You can do it like so:

NSMutableArray *newarray = [NSMutableArray array];

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you didn't initialize `newarray`. You need to do

```
newarray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

But also note that adding `self.tableData[0]` to it is different from adding another alloc'ed and init'ed `Cell` to it because the former increases the reference count on `self.tableData[0]`, while the latter creates a new `Cell` object.

This also means that if you make a new `Cell` object and add it to the mutable array, and later on modified that object in the mutable array, it wouldn't change the cell in the first array. But if you did it the first way, it would.